# GIT Submodules in VSTS

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, git-submodules

I have a VSTS project with a git repo called for example projectA. I have a another he repo has some submodules that are also required as part of the software projects development for example project_common. i want add project_common to be added to projectA but still remain as its own one repo. is there a way of doing this in VSTS ?.

Comment: Currently, the project_common configured as sub-module in projectA?

Comment: In your ProjectA just add the submodules like `git submodule add https://xxx.visualstudio.com/project_common/...  Common`

Comment: thanks for your reply done as described. it pulls in the project_common when i run the git submodule add.  Do i j commit the .gitsmodules fback to my repo or do i need to add the common project also